# SQL query to get all parent and child for each records in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, hierarchy, recursive-query

Current data in the `Emp` table:

```
EmpId   Name         RejEmpId   DOJ             DOL         
----------------------------------------------------------
1       Name1           NULL    10-12-2014      12-06-2015  
2       Name1           1       06-04-2016      24-12-2016      
3       Name1           2       01-04-2017      NULL        
4       Name2           NULL    22-12-2014      21-07-2015  
5       Name2           4       10-04-2016      22-12-2016      
6       Name3           NULL    10-05-2015      NULL            
7       Name4           NULL    10-05-2015      NULL
```

I want to get custom columns (All Parent And Child EmpId, Actual DOJ, Actual DOL)

```
EmpId Name  RejEmpId DOJ        DOL         All             
                                            Parent              
                                            And
                                            Child   Actual      Actual
                                            EmpId   DOJ         DOL         
1    Name1  NULL    10-12-2014  12-06-2015  1.2.3   10-12-2014  NULL
2    Name1  1       06-04-2016  24-12-2016  1.2.3   10-12-2014  NULL
3    Name1  2       01-04-2017  NULL        1.2.3   10-12-2014  NULL
4    Name2  NULL    22-12-2014  21-07-2015  4.5     22-12-2014  22-12-2016
5    Name2  4       10-04-2016  22-12-2016  4.5     22-12-2014  22-12-2016
6    Name3  NULL    10-05-2015  NULL        6       10-05-2015  NULL
7    Name4  NULL    10-05-2015  NULL        7       10-05-2015  NULL
8    Name5  NULL    12-06-2015  20-12-2016  8       12-06-2015  20-12-2016
```

Comment: What is the question? "Write the query for me" isn't a question. There are a *LOT* of duplicate questions that show how to write hierarchical queries with `hierarchyid` or recursive CTEs. Have you tried something? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: i did using https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child

Comment: i did using https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child All Possible Parents In A Column section. i could not manage to do Actual DOJ and Actual DOL. Actual DOJ is first parent DOJ and Actual DOL last child DOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can query as below:

For concatenation you can use Stuff, Getting first value of DOJ you can use FIRST_VALUE function which is in SQL Server 2012+ and similarly for DOL you can use LAST_VALUE function as below:

```
Select emp.EmpId, Emp.[Name], RejEmpId, emp.DOJ, DOL, concatStr as [AllParent and Child EmpId]
    ,FIRST_VALUE(DOJ) over(partition by emp.[Name] order by EmpId) as ActualDOJ
    ,LAST_VALUE(DOL) over(partition by emp.[Name] order by EmpId rows between current row and unbounded following) as AcualDOL
    from #empdata emp
cross apply (
    Select [Name], concatStr = stuff((select concat('.', EmpId) from #empdata e where e.[Name] = o.[Name] for xml path('')),1,1,'')  
    from #empdata o
    group by [Name]
) c where emp.[Name] = c.[Name]
```

Output as below:

```
+-------+-------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+
| EmpId | Name  | RejEmpId |    DOJ     |    DOL     | AllParent and Child EmpId | ActualDOJ  |  AcualDOL  |
+-------+-------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+
|     1 | Name1 | NULL     | 2014-12-10 | 2015-06-12 |                     1.2.3 | 2014-12-10 | NULL       |
|     2 | Name1 | 1        | 2016-04-06 | 2016-12-24 |                     1.2.3 | 2014-12-10 | NULL       |
|     3 | Name1 | 2        | 2017-04-01 | NULL       |                     1.2.3 | 2014-12-10 | NULL       |
|     4 | Name2 | NULL     | 2014-12-22 | 2015-07-21 |                       4.5 | 2014-12-22 | 2016-12-22 |
|     5 | Name2 | 4        | 2016-04-10 | 2016-12-22 |                       4.5 | 2014-12-22 | 2016-12-22 |
|     6 | Name3 | NULL     | 2015-05-10 | NULL       |                         6 | 2015-05-10 | NULL       |
|     7 | Name4 | NULL     | 2015-05-10 | NULL       |                         7 | 2015-05-10 | NULL       |
+-------+-------+----------+------------+------------+---------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: same name but it is different employee means, what happend

Comment: For that you need to provide a column which has correct Employee identifier attribute

Comment: want to maintain unqiueness for same employee. is it correct.